# How to manage a separate thread/job within a eclipse job?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Here is my question :-

I am in the process of building a client-server application where I post the request to the server to generate 2 XML's for me (server fetches the information from the DB and generates XML based on this fetched info). Now, once the server has created these 2 XML's, server streams back these 2 files to the client so that client can save them on their machine.

(POSTING + READING FROM THE STREAM) IS ONE JOB. Without 2nd operation i.e. reading from stream, Job is incomplete.

I have created a Job in eclipse which posts the request to the server and takes the streamed files and save them on client machine. Posting the request to the server is a asynchronous call (it will return immediately). Once call is posted and returned immediately, I start polling on the Network Pipe for any data sever has sent(in this case it is the XML's data) & write it into a file.

As you can see here that reading the XML's from the stream and writing them into a file is part of the overall main Job but, still a separate job in itself (should be run in a separate thread). If User cancels the main job, reading from the network stream should also be cancelled.

So, basically my requirement is a cacellable job which does this entire thing. Reading from the stream should be separate Thread/Job but should be inside the main Job. If user cancels the main Job, this innner Job (reading from the Job) should also get cancelled.

Can you guys suggests a clean approach for doing this?

-Ankit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a mainjob and within that mainjob you can create a subjob. If the mainjob is cancelled you can delegate the cancel to the subjob.

I created a simple view with two buttons. One for starting the jobs and the other for cancelling.

```java
package rcpexperiments;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Status;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.IJobChangeEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.JobChangeAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class View extends ViewPart
{
  private Job mainJob;

  @Override
  public void createPartControl(final Composite parent)
  {
    final Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Start Job");
    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
    {

      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
      {
        mainJob = new Job("Main Job")
        {

          private boolean canceled = false;

          @Override
          protected void canceling()
          {
            System.out.println("Cancel requested.");
            canceled = true;
          }

          @Override
          protected IStatus run(final IProgressMonitor monitor)
          {
            final Job subJob = createSubJob();
            subJob.schedule();
            canceled = false;
            while (!canceled)
            {
              try
              {
                Thread.sleep(100);
              }
              catch (final InterruptedException e)
              {
              }
            }
            subJob.cancel();
            System.out.println("Main Job is canceled.");
            return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
          }

          private Job createSubJob()
          {
            return new Job("Sub Job")
            {
              boolean subJobCancel = false;

              @Override
              protected void canceling()
              {
                subJobCancel = true;
              }

              @Override
              protected IStatus run(final IProgressMonitor monitor)
              {
                System.out.println("Sub Job started.");
                while (!subJobCancel)
                {
                  try
                  {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                  }
                  catch (final InterruptedException e)
                  {
                  }
                }
                System.out.println("Sub Job canceled");
                return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
              }

            };
          }

        };
        mainJob.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter()
        {
          @Override
          public void done(final IJobChangeEvent event)
          {
            System.out.println("Job finished by " + event.getResult());
          }
        });
        mainJob.schedule();

        System.out.println("Main Job started.");
      };

    });
    final Button cancel = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    cancel.setText("Cancel");
    cancel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
    {

      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
      {
        mainJob.cancel();
      }

    });
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void setFocus()
  {
  }

}
```

I hope that is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. It is very close to what i need. Your answer has surely given me a direction. I will modify the code to my requirements. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It seemed to me like a bit of a hassle to define subjobs the way Micheal K. suggested. So I went looking into the Eclipse docs and found that the [Job](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2Fjobs%2FJob.html) class defines a static method called createProgressGroup and can be used as follows (same doc) which does roughly the same thing:

```
Job parseJob, compileJob;
IProgressMonitor pm = Job.getJobManager().createProgressGroup();
try {
   pm.beginTask("Building", 10);
   parseJob.setProgressGroup(pm, 5);
   parseJob.schedule();
   compileJob.setProgressGroup(pm, 5);
   compileJob.schedule();
   parseJob.join();
   compileJob.join();
} finally {
   pm.done();
}
```

Please note that the IJobManager.getJobManager is deprecated.